# How can I static check the null pointer exception in Java?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, static-analysis

There are some `NullPointerException` crashes in my Android project. How can I static check or test the `NullPointerException` crash in Java / Android?

Comment: you mean you want to proceed even though there is null pointer?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking where to get/how to use a static analyzer to do this or are you asking how to *write* a static analyzer to do this? In the former case this is mistagged - in the latter case the question is way too broad/open-ended.

Comment: Use findbugs to analyze your code

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to avoid a `nullPointerException` at runtime is to surround your piece of code in a *null check* like this:

```
if (mySomething != null) {
    doSomething(mySomething);
}
```

This will only use `mySomething` if it is not `null` and can be used, thereby avoiding `nullPointerException`s. You can also *catch* a `nullPointerExcepton`, but this is not a good idea.

---

You can also use a *static analysis* tool like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or IntelliJ's built in inspections to analyze your code and tell you if it could produce a `nullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article which describes best practices for the most common cases of NPE: http://javarevisited.blogspot.hu/2013/05/ava-tips-and-best-practices-to-avoid-nullpointerexception-program-application.html

You could parametrize your code analyzer tool to catch these cases.

Comment: Instead of just posting a link, it would be best to post the relevant parts of the article into your answer. Otherwise, your answer could become useless when that blog goes down.